# Using Wild Cards in Select Statements in Excel VBA 2013

Tags: excel, vba

As a beginner I am having trouble with syntax in VBA. The Select statement as written below does not execute the way I thought it should. It has to do with the use of the wildcard. If I default to a specific case (SAY "FA00001") it flows correctly. When I use the wild card every Part number falls in to the last case.

**What am I doing incorrectly with the use of the wild card?**

```
Select Case True
   Case PartNumber Like "FA*", "CH*"
   Case PartNumber Like "FB*"
   Case PartNumber <> "FA*", "FB*", "CH*"
End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the Like statements - it's with your Case Syntax.  You need to put *the full case* after each comma when you have multiple cases.  The case `Case PartNumber Like "FA*", "CH*"` will match on either `PartNumber Like "FA*" = True` (which makes sense) or `"CH*" = True`, which doesn't.

Try this:

```
Select Case True
   Case PartNumber Like "FA*", PartNumber Like "CH*"
   Case PartNumber Like "FB*"
   Case PartNumber <> "FA*", PartNumber <> "FB*", PartNumber <> "CH*"
End Select
```

Comment: Nice :). Didn't know Select permitted it

Comment: @AnalystCave.com - It's similar to the C style idiom of multiple switch cases.  VBA doesn't have fall-through (no `break;`), so it uses the comma to allow the same type of syntax.

Comment: thanks, I thought i had a syntax problem. this works as cleanly.

Comment: @Matthew, if this worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. That will help others in the future, as well as giving you a few points so you can start to build reputation and take advantage of other great SO features.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use `Like` in a VBA `Select Case` statement, and having `True` on your `Select Case` line is likely breaking things as well.

Try this:

```
Select Case Left(PartNumber, 2)
  Case "FA", "CH"
    'code here
  Case "FB"
    'code here
  Case Else
    'code here
End Select
```

Comment: You can use Like, and having True is also not an issue

Comment: Thanks, that executes fine. I did see when I  searched on stackoverflow the approach i started with. that is why i went that way.

Comment: @AnalystCave.com while that may be, I've never seen it used that way in any of the examples I've ever come across on the web. Not saying it _won't_ work, but I know my solution will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just a small change:

```
  Select Case True
            Case PartNumber Like "FA*"
   JumpFa:
             'your code here
            Case PartNumber Like "CH*"
               GoTo JumpFA
            Case PartNumber Like "FB*"
               'code here
            Case Else
               'code here
        End Select
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd advocate a Goto.  It defeats the purpose of the Select by allowing multiple entry points to arbitrary code...

Comment: I agree. While that will likely work, it would be confusing to those coming along later.